# Bitwise XOR on two digit hex string in Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift3, xor

I want to get Bitwise XOR value from 1st two strings of array and then result of 1st two should be XORed with 3rd element of array and result of this should be XORed with 4th element of array and so on..

Array is `["a2", "09", "00", "00", "00", "01", "00", "00", "00", "10", "00"]`

Final answer will also be bitWise XOR value

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code to get your result

`let numbers = pairs.flatMap{Int($0, radix: 16)}`

`let xor = numbers.reduce(0, {$0^$1})`

`let result = String(format: "%02x", xor)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Int(String, radix: 16)` to convert a hex string number to an `Int`. Using this initializer of `Int`, you can use `flatMap` to convert the hexadecimal strings to integers.

Then you can use `reduce` to iterate through the array and take the XOR value (using the built-in `^` operator) of your current result and the next element of the array.

```
let hexStrings = ["a2", "09", "00", "00", "00", "01", "00", "00", "00", "10", "00"]
let numbers = hexStrings.flatMap{Int($0, radix: 16)}
numbers
let xor = numbers.reduce(0, {$0^$1}) //186 as it should be
```

If you need the final value in hex, you can use `String(Int, radix:16)`:

```
let xorHex = String(xor, radix: 16) // "ba"
```

Comment: Glad I could help. If you found my answer useful, please consider accepting it.

Comment: It works like a charm. But i tried with two 16 length hex strings. Initially 0 is missing. Remaining string is coming as expected.